# Another class not mapped In Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Im studying the Spring doc in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html. When I create another class, the methods are not mapped.

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ExampleError {

@RequestMapping("/testmap")
public String test() {
    return "TEST 2";
}

}
```

My main class works fine:

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Example {

@RequestMapping("/")
String home() {
    return "Hello World!";
}

@RequestMapping("/test")
String teste() {
    return "TEST 1";
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
}
```

}

Can someone clarify me?

Regards

Comment: This must be `@ComponentScan` issue, can you share your project/package structure?

Comment: You´re right! Im new in Spring world and didnt use the annotation ComponentScan in the root class (in the case, Example.java).  Now works! Thanks for help!